# what is wrong in this code for select the data place and making backup

Tags: vb.net

```
Sub backup()
   con.Open()
   Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE ['" & TextBox1.Text & "'] TO DISK = N'D:\5-2016\Backup.bak' WITH COPY_ONLY", con)
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
   con.Close()
End Sub
```

Hello everyone, I want to select the database in `textbox` in the form but the code does not work.

Comment: Saying "it doesn't work" is never adequate.  Presumably an exception is thrown?  Have you examined that exception?  If not, do so.  If so, what are the details?

Comment: all i want to select the data name from the pc and make backup and This code does not give anything not given any errors

Comment: So what exactly does not work? Does your sql command get the wrong string? Is it the right string but not executed properly? Is it executed, but just not written anywhere?

Comment: it does not make any backup file i mean after click the backup button i did find any *.bak file

Comment: Additional information: Database 'C:\Users\hany\Desktop\hanysql\hanysql\bin\Debug\Database5.mdf' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.   this is the massage

Comment: So it looks like the file name is wrong? What is entered in your textBox1? And what should the filename be?

Comment: i made a open dialog box to select the data

Comment: RE: "Additional information: " you cannot enter the name of the file as database name. This is not how it works. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms186865.aspx